# JavaScript based Audio player.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find an Audio-Player, javascript based. I have tried a bunch of them, but was unable to find one with "Analytic", "Caption", "Control-Bar" etc other features.

Can I have some suggestions, where I can find such an audio player. Preferably free. ;)

Best 
Zeeshan

Answer (score 4):

Check out [html5media](http://html5media.info/). You don't have to write JS:). This library gives you the audio tag working with most modern browsers. Here is more about looping: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_audio_loop.asp.

Comment: Yes - use HTML5 audio and provide a fallback for browsers that don't support it.

Answer (score 2):

[Yahoo Media Player](http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/) should be perfect for you.